# R: Combining lists with csv metadata

Tags: r, csv, metadata

I am having a bit of trouble with some work with text files and the associated metadata for the files. I can read in the files, pre-process them, and then convert them to a readable format for the lda package I am using ([using this guide by Sievert](http://cpsievert.github.io/LDAvis/reviews/reviews.html)). Example below:

```
#Reading the files
corpus <- file.path("Folder/Fiction/texts")
corpus <- list.files(corpus)
corpus <- lapply(corpus, readLines)

***pre-processing functions removed for space***

corp.list <- strsplit(corpus, "[[:space:]]+")

# compute the table of terms:
corpterm.table <- table(unlist(corp.list))
corpterm.table <- sort(corpterm.table, decreasing = TRUE)

***removing stopwords, again removed for space***

# now put the corpus into the format required by the lda package:
getCorp.terms <- function(x) {
  index <- match(x, vocabCorp)
  index <- index[!is.na(index)]
  rbind(as.integer(index - 1), as.integer(rep(1, length(index))))
  }
  corpus <- lapply(corp.list, getCorp.terms)
```

At this point, the `corpus` variable is a list of document tokens with a separate vector per document, but has been detached from its file path, and the name of the file. Herein is where my problem begins: I have a csv with the metadata for the texts (their file names, titles, authors, years, genres, etc.) which I would like to have associated with each vector of tokens, in order to easily model my information over time, by gender, etc.

I am unsure of how to do this, but am guessing it would need to be done as the files are being read, and not merged after I have manipulated the document texts. I would imagine it would be something that would look like:

```
corpus.f <- file.path (stuff)
corpus <- list.files(corpus)
corpus <- lapply(corpus, ReadLines)
corpus.df <- as.data.frame(c(corpus.f,corpus))
corpus.info <- read.csv(stuff.csv)
```

And from there using the merge or match function in combination to associate each document (or vector of document tokens) with its correct row of metadata.

Comment: what is the structure of your data at this after this step: corpus <- lapply(corpus, readLines)

Comment: @Chris The structure is a large list that looks like this: 
 `List of 1128
 $ : chr [1:61616] "word " "word" "word " "word " ...
 $ : chr [1:108093] ", " ", " ", " ", " ...
 $ : chr [1:29334] ", " ", " ", " ", " ...`
And so on, with one vector per document.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this:

```
pth <- file.path("Folder/Fiction/texts")
fi <- list.files(pth)
corpus <- lapply(fi, readLines)
corp.list <- strsplit(corpus, "[[:space:]]+") 
setNames(object = corp.list, nm = fi) -> corp.list
```

Comment: Awesome. This worked for appending the names of the files to each text in the list. My next task is to figure out how to add the text themselves to the csv as a single column.